# Powershell Active Directory Attributes Creating User

Tags: powershell, active-directory

My code:

```
New-ADUser -samaccountname first_last -Name "first last" -UserPrincipalName aaa@egc.gov.vm -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "p@ssw0rd" -Force) -Enabled $true -PasswordNeverExpires $true -Path 'OU=EGC,DC=egc,DC=gov,DC=vm' -givenname 'first' -sn 'last' -displayname 'display name' -description 'IC NO' -title 'Job Title' -division '3' -physicaldeliveryofficename 'EGNC HQ' -telephonenumber '2424955' -mail 'first.last@egc.gov.bn' -department 'egnc hq' -company 'ministry PMO' -streetaddress 'Full Address Here' -postalcode 'BB3333'
```

One of the Error:

```
New-ADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'telephonenumber'.
```

The error follows the the following LDAP attributes:

- sn
- physicalDeliveryOfficeName
- telephonenumber
- mail

User creation works if I remove the mentioned attributes.

Any fix for this?

---

Answer for:

- sn is Surname
- telephonenumber is officephone (Thanks to David Johnson)
- physicalDeliveryOfficeName is office (Thanks to David Johnson)
- mail is email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which telephone number?

- officephone
- mobilephone

Comment: you are right, it was -officephone! I found out sn is actually Surname.

Comment: Now i need to find 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName' which refers to 'Office' field and 'mail' which refers to 'E-mail' field in AD

Comment: physical Delivery Office name?

Comment: yes! physicalDeliveryOfficeName is office where as mail is just email! lol

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but someone may actually need to amend the *telephonenumber* attribute or any other attribute that does not show up when you run `get-aduser username properties *`

Even though you receive the error when amending the *telephoneNumber* attribute using the syntax as attempted by the OP - you CAN actually amend the telephoneNumber attribute using the syntax below:

`Set-ADUser username -add @{telephoneNumber="000 1111 1111"}`

As the telephonenumber attribute is not a multivalue attribute If the attribute already has a value it will return an error.  To amend the attribute regardless of whether there is a value or not - use `-replace` instead of `-add`

`Set-ADUser username -replace @{telephoneNumber="000 1111 1111"}`